# What is wrong with this interface?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

can interface contain body? help me solve this part

```
public interface Figures
{
  public void printMessage (String s)
  {
    System.out.println ("This figure is " + s);
  }
  public double area ();    // to calculate the area of the figure
}
```

Comment: Nope, an interface can't contain a method body.  Use `default` if you must do this.

Comment: How can i use it give me snippet pls

Comment: @AMohamedSakeel do this         public default void printMessage(String s)

Comment: @markspace You're contradicting yourself. An interface can contain a method body, if you use `default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is a completely "abstract class" that is used to group related methods with empty bodies

```
public interface Figures
{
  public void printMessage (String s);
  public double area ();    // to calculate the area of the figure
}
```

To access the interface methods, the interface must be "implemented" (kinda like inherited) by another class with the implements keyword (instead of extends). The body of the interface method is provided by the "implement" class.

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp) is well explained

This is the example from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp)

```
// Interface
interface Animal {
  public void animalSound(); // interface method (does not have a body)
  public void sleep(); // interface method (does not have a body)
}

// Pig "implements" the Animal interface
class Pig implements Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    // The body of animalSound() is provided here
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
  public void sleep() {
    // The body of sleep() is provided here
    System.out.println("Zzz");
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pig myPig = new Pig();  // Create a Pig object
    myPig.animalSound();
    myPig.sleep();
  }
}
```

Comment: Then, where to print output

Comment: In the class that implements your interface

Comment: Since Java 8 there are default methods which allow you to provide a default implementation of an interface method inside the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, we can provide default implantation to an interface method using the `default` keyword

```java
public interface Figures
{
  public default void printMessage (String s)
  {
    System.out.println ("This figure is " + s);
  }
  public double area ();    // to calculate the area of the figure
}
```

Comment: is this the standard method instead of Implement

Comment: What do you mean by **standard method**?

Comment: Can interface have implemetation?

Comment: yes since Java 8 :)

Comment: I need to use Implement class instead of using `Default`

Comment: In this case, I think you can use what is proposed by **@Oscar Ernesto Gonzalez** in his response